# Does the Asus Zenbook (ASUS 15.6" UX501JW-DN233H ) have a backlit keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, asus-laptop, zenbook

Just got the laptop today.  Read online that the laptop has a backlit keyboard, those were 'pro' though, and were assigned to the <kbd>F3</kbd>and <kbd>F4</kbd> keys.

My laptop however does not have any image on the f3 and f4 keys (the one with the keyboard image).

Is there another way for me to check using software?  I am running windows 8.1.  Or could someone verify if my laptop has a backlit keyboard.!

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked about a year ago. But I have a laptop with the same model number, and I thought I could add my information. Mine does not have any functions on the F3 or F4 and it does not have backlit keys. Note that if I hold down function and F3 or F4, the brightness down/up does appear on screen but nothing happens to the keys, because they are not backlit.

Some UX501JW do not have backlit keys, but if you think that yours might, you can install the drivers from Asus and then try function + F4. If yours is like mine, nothing will happen because there's no backlight.